# Devolver ultimo id de una inserción

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-19c

Estoy haciendo una inserción con consulta interna pero me devuelve un error cuando devuelvo un ultimo id, el ejemplo seria algo asi

`(INSERT INTO table_name (id, description) (SELECT id, description from dual) RETURNING id INTO :ult_id)` ,

me dice que "SQL no terminado correctamente", sin embargo lo ejecuto asi

`(INSERT INTO table_name (id, description) VALUES (id, description) RETURNING id INTO :ult_id)`

me devuelve bien los datos, alguna idea de lo que sucede?

Comment: EL insert into select no necesita ese paréntesis alrededor, hasta donde recuerdo

Comment: saca todos los parentesis y volve a probarlo.. puede ser eso...

Comment: Ya lo intente y aun no devuelve

Comment: La [sintaxis](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#i2111652) nos dice que la cláusula `RETURNING` va con la cláusula `VALUES`. Si los valores vienen de una consulta que regresa mas de un valor, ¿de cuál registro se tomarían los valores para `RETURNING`?, considerando que no se retorna un conjunto de registros.

Answer (score 0):

Descubrí que para que funcione llamando desde php se debe tener en cuenta el tamaño de buffer para cada variable de entrada o salida del procedimiento, lo que aun no entiendo es ¿Por qué con las inserciones con búsqueda interna no devuelve el ultimo id?